# Can i set password permanent in tortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoise-svn

Is it possible to set the password permanent so it doesn't always prompt asking me for password whenever I do changes to my project?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed. You can save the log in information to the URL:

[image]

If you click on the lock, you will see this screen:

[image]

Enter your login credentials here and it *should* stop prompting you. Came across this problem myself when starting use tortoise and this is what solved it for me...

Hope it helps!

Comment: How can I get to the window on your first screenshot?

Comment: @starcorn - thats the synchronize window. Access it from the tortoise menu (right click > tortoise)

Comment: I don't have that option when I right click, I only got these http://i.imgur.com/OA9ds.png

Comment: not sure i recognise that menu to be honest! On my system, i created a project folder and converted it to a repository. Whenever i make changes to the code i save the changes, right click on the folder/repository and click synchronize. From there i can push or pull to bit-bucket.

Comment: Ok, now I just realized that you are using tortoise bitbucket, and not the SVN version. So yeah there's not sync option in SVN.